# how to compare json arrays in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am having this issue comparing the array from a json file within a function of typescript.
The index.ts is this: Hint 1:  Do not hard-code references to context variables like 'Profession' Hint 2:  Conditions can be nested, n-levels deep. Convert the condition into postfix-notation. These are the kinda hints I have in solving the problem.

```
import conditionInput from "./condition.json";

/**
 * Evaluate a condition against the context.
 * @param condition A domain-specific language (DSL) JSON object.
 * @param context An object of keys and values
 * @return boolean
 */
function evaluate(
  condition: typeof conditionInput,
  context: { [key: string]: string | undefined }
  // count=0
): boolean {
  // Your task is to implement this function such that it evaluates the imported condition.json against the context. Strings prefixed with '$' are variables and should have their values drawn from the context.
  // Hint 1:  Do not hard-code references to context variables like 'Profession'
  // Hint 2:  Conditions can be nested, n-levels deep
  // Convert the condition into postfix-notation

  // Ideally, one value must remain in the result stack with the last operation's result
  return false;
}

/**
 * Click "run" to execute the test cases, which should pass after your implementation.
 */
(function () {
  const cases = [
    {
      context: {
        State: "Alabama",
        Profession: "Software development",
      },
      expected: true,
    },
    {
      context: {
        State: "Texas",
      },
      expected: true,
    },
    {
      context: {
        State: "Alabama",
        Profession: "Gaming",
      },
      expected: false,
    },
    {
      context: {
        State: "Utah",
      },
      expected: false,
    },
    {
      context: {
        Profession: "Town crier",
      },
      expected: false,
    },
    {
      context: {
        Profession: "Tradesperson",
      },
      expected: true,
    },
  ];

  for (const c of cases) {
    const actual = evaluate(conditionInput, c.context);
    console.log(actual === c.expected ? "yay :-)" : "nay :-(");
  }
})();
```

And the consition.json is this:

```
[
  "OR",
  [
    "AND",
    ["==", "$State", "Alabama"],
    ["==", "$Profession", "Software development"]
  ],
  ["AND", ["==", "$State", "Texas"]],
  ["OR", ["==", "$Profession", "Tradesperson"]]
]
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No, i'm new to typescript and a friend gave it to me as a challenge but i really can not focus on the problem as i don't know how typescript works.

Comment: Please ask more specific questions about what parts about typescript that confuses you. Stack overflow isn't a website where you just post a problem and people solve it for you

Comment: My suggestion is that you try to focus on the problem first and figure out how you would solve it using pseudo-code or some language you're comfortable with. Then, you try your best implementing it in typescript/javascript. If you face some issue, you post it here

Comment: This is in fact a coding test from a company i know!

Comment: Yes, it was a test and I am not joining the firm. I wanted to solve the problem still. But here at stackoverflow people judge you before even solving your problem. I am really new to  TypeScript and I really did not know anything about it. The job that I applied was a react job and usually you work with javascript in react not typescript. The firm still insisted on taking the test of typescript which i still tried and in the end told them i couldn't do it and posted the question here just to know how things would work and what would the solution be. So, THANK YOU all for helping...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isConditionalOperator(toCheck) {
    switch (toCheck) {
        case 'AND':
        case 'OR':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

function isOperator(toCheck) {
    switch (toCheck) {
        case '==':
        case '<':
        case '>':
        case '<=':
        case '>=':
        case '!=':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

function compute(a, operator, b) {
    return operator(a, b);
}

function symbolToOperator(symbol) {
    switch (symbol) {
        case '==': return doubleEqual;
        case '<': return lessThan;
        case '>': return greaterThan;
        case '>=': return lessThanEqual;
        case '<=': return greaterThanEqual;
        case '!=': return notEqual;
        case 'OR': return orFn;
        case 'AND': return andFn;
    }
}

function andFn(a, b) {return a && b; }
function orFn(a, b) { return a || b; }
function notEqual(a, b) { return a != b; }
function doubleEqual(a, b) { return a == b; }
function lessThan(a, b) { return a < b; }
function greaterThan(a, b) { return a > b; }
function lessThanEqual(a, b) { return a <= b; }
function greaterThanEqual(a, b) { return a >= b; }

function makePostfixNotationStack(arr: Array<any>, postfixNotationConditionStack: Array<any>): Array<any> {
    arr.push(arr.shift());
    arr.forEach((element: any) => {
        if (element instanceof Array) {
            makePostfixNotationStack(element, postfixNotationConditionStack);
        } else if ((element == 'OR' || element == 'AND') && arr.length > 2) {
            postfixNotationConditionStack.push(element);
        } else if (arr.length == 3) {
            postfixNotationConditionStack.push(element);
        }
    });
    return postfixNotationConditionStack;
}


/**
 * Evaluate a condition against the context.
 * @param condition A domain-specific language (DSL) JSON object.
 * @param context An object of keys and values
 * @return boolean
 */
function evaluate(
    postfixNotationConditionStack: Array<string>,
    context: { [key: string]: string | undefined }
    // count=0
): boolean {
    let postfixExecutionStack: any[] = ['|'];

    postfixNotationConditionStack.forEach(function (current) {
        if (isOperator(current)) {
            let a = postfixExecutionStack.pop();
            let b = postfixExecutionStack.pop();
            let operator = symbolToOperator(current);
            if (typeof b == "string") {
                b = context[b.substring(1)];
            }
            postfixExecutionStack.push(
                compute(a, operator, b)
            );
        } else if (isConditionalOperator(current)) {
            let operator = symbolToOperator(current);

            postfixExecutionStack[postfixExecutionStack.length - 2] == '|' ? postfixExecutionStack.pop() : null;
            while (postfixExecutionStack[postfixExecutionStack.length - 2] != '|') {
                let a = postfixExecutionStack.pop();
                let b = postfixExecutionStack.pop();
                if (typeof b == "string") {
                    b = context[b.substring(1)];
                }
                postfixExecutionStack.push(
                    compute(a, operator, b)
                );
            };
            postfixExecutionStack[postfixExecutionStack.length - 2] != '|' ? postfixExecutionStack.push('|') : null;
        } else {
            postfixExecutionStack.push(current);
        }
    });

    return postfixExecutionStack[1];
    
    // Ideally, one value must remain in the result stack with the last operation's result
    //   return false;
}

/**
 * Click "run" to execute the test cases, which should pass after your implementation.
 */
(function () {
    const cases = [
        {
            context: {
                State: "Alabama",
                Profession: "Software development",
            },
            expected: true,
        },
        {
            context: {
                State: "Texas",
            },
            expected: true,
        },
        {
            context: {
                State: "Alabama",
                Profession: "Gaming",
            },
            expected: false,
        },
        {
            context: {
                State: "Utah",
            },
            expected: false,
        },
        {
            context: {
                Profession: "Town crier",
            },
            expected: false,
        },
        {
            context: {
                Profession: "Tradesperson",
            },
            expected: true,
        },
    ];

    let conditionInput = [
        "OR", [
            "AND", ["==", "$State", "Alabama"],
            ["==", "$Profession", "Software development"]
        ],
        ["AND", ["==", "$State", "Texas"]],
        ["OR", ["==", "$Profession", "Tradesperson"]]
    ];

    let postfixNotationConditionStack: string[] = makePostfixNotationStack(conditionInput, []);
    
    for (const c of cases) {
        const actual = evaluate(postfixNotationConditionStack, c.context);
        console.log(actual === c.expected ? "yay :-)" : "nay :-(");
    }
})();
```

Comment: Reference : https://www.parsonsmatt.org/2014/07/07/postfixjs.html#:~:text=Postfix%20arithmetic%20means%20that%20the,with%20its%20equivalent%205%203%20%2B%20.

Comment: A request to the person who downvoted my answer. Could you please leave a comment with reason for it.

Comment: Please don't just paste code without any explanation. This website is for teaching and learning. By just posting a solution, you're just solving the current problem, but not helping the asker to understand how to solve similar problems in the future.

Comment: It is throwing errors of typescript. I don't like typescript. Why do we have to define a type everytime we declare and use a variable??